# Вернуть массив с текстами внутри тегов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно написать функцию которая вернет массив с текстами внутри тегов - a

```js
const aTeg = document.querySelector("a")
console.log(aTeg.textContent)
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link zero" data-link="0">zero</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link first" data-link="1">five</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link two" data-link="2">two</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link three" data-link="3">three</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link four" data-link="4">one</a>
</nav>
```

Я получил текст первого тега а
Но мне нужно получить массив с текстами  внутри тегов - a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')
const texts = Array.from(links).map((link) => link.textContent)

console.log(texts)
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link zero" data-link="0">zero</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link first" data-link="1">five</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link two" data-link="2">two</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link three" data-link="3">three</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link four" data-link="4">one</a>
</nav>
```

P.S.
querySelector возвращает первый элемент который он находит на странице с заданным селектором.
querySelectorAll ищет все элементы по заданному селектору

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @kurmanbek Если ответ вам помог, то пожалуйста не забудьте поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа